# Extract data lists from Mongo Documents

Tags: mongodb

As a mongo/nosql newbie with a RDBMS background I wondered what's the best way to proceed.

Currently I've got a large set of documents, containing in some fields, what I consider as "reference datas". 
My need is to display in a search interface summarizing the possible values of those "reference fields" to further proceed a filter on my documents set.

Let's take a very simple and stupid example about nourishment.
Here is an extract of some mongo documents:

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "apple", "category": "fruit"}
{ "_id": 1, "name": "orange", "category": "fruit"}
{ "_id": 1, "name": "cucumber", "category": "vegetable"}
```

In the appplication I'd like to have a selectbox displaying all the possible values for "category". Here it would display "fruit" and "vegetable".

What's the best way to proceed ?

- extract datas from the existing documents ?
- create some reference documents listing unique possible values (as I would do in RDBMS  )
- store reference data in a rdbms and programatically link mongo and rdbms...
- something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is the easiest to implement and should be efficient if you have indexes properly set (see [distinct command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct)), so I would go with this.

You could also choose the second option (linking to a reference collection - RDBMS way) which trades *performance* (you will need more queries for fetching data) for *space* (you will need less space). Also, this option is preferred if the category is used in other collections as well.

I would advise against using a mixed system (NoSQL + RDBMS) in this case as the other options are better.

You could also store category values directly in application code - depends on your use case. Sometimes it makes sense, although any RDBMS fanatic would burst into tears (or worse) if you tell him that. YMMV. ;)